# How to get multiple columns in one variable in mysql query

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions, group-concat

I have the table

```
Articles -------- id,name,type_id
Type--------------id,name
article_type ----------article_id , type_id
```

I using this query

```
select A.name from types A 
inner join article_type B on ( B.type_id = A.id and article_id = 10)
```

Now this query is working but it gives me separate rows but i want all types in one variables so that i can display in table format like

```
Article name ------------types
milk--------------------dairy , persishable , costly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
  SELECT a.name AS article_name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) AS types
    FROM ARTICLES a
    JOIN ARTICLE_TYPE at ON at.article_id = a.id
    JOIN TYPE t ON t.id = at.type_id
GROUP BY a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the trick is to use `CONCAT`, as in `SELECT CONCAT(A.name, ',',B.type) AS synth FROM...`